# Hide CollectionViewCell without updating the data source

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to use `collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath])` and keep my data source intact. The purpose of this wanted behaviour is to be able to apply filters to my collection view and easily revert thanks to `collectionView.reloadData()`, and keep the cool built in animation of deletion.

Is there a workaround to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data source always needs to match what is displayed in the collection view.

The easiest way would be to have two arrays for your data. `allData` and `displayedData`. Your collection view would always be looking at `displayedData` as the data source.

If the user adds a filter, you update the value in `displayedData` and run the animation your want. When the user removes the filter, you set `displayedData` back to `allData` and animate again.